# Справочники по PHP

Tags: php

Подскажите ссылки на качественные онлайн-справочники по PHP.

Comment: php.net чем не угодил?

Comment: Еще можно http://phpclub.ru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [phpfaq.ru](http://phpfaq.ru) - многие основы пхп, читать обязательно.
- [php.su](http://php.su) - уроки пхп.
- [intuit.ru](http://intuit.ru) - курс "Язык программирования PHP".

Из книг - советую Котерова.

Answer (score 1):

Очень грамотные [статьи](http://phpclub.ru/detail/) на темы реализации различных связок, приёмов. С примерами и разжевыванием.

Answer (score 1):

- для нубов: [softtime.ru/bookphp/help.php](http://www.softtime.ru/bookphp/help.php)
- в первую очередь иду сюда: [spravkaweb.ru/php](http://www.spravkaweb.ru/php)
- самый актуальный: [php.net](http://php.net/)